# Using various tools of Valgrind during compilation

Tags: valgrind

Using the different Valgrind tools for profiling and debugging individual programs is easy. I am working on a big project with lot of modules and packages. (for Router SoC).

On Building the model, how do I use Valgrind for debugging during compilation of the entire model? Should I include Valgrind in the makefile (Because I don't want to run Valgrind separately for every individual file)? All I want is during the compilation of the entire big model, I want Valgrind's output log files for every individual C program?

Comment: I don't get the point. Probably you should split your project in many tests and then run valgrind on the tests singularly.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like `valgrind --trace-children=yes --log-file="log.%p" the-whole-shebang`.  The %p is substituted for pid.  You can throw in some `--trace-children-skip` or `--trace-children-skip-by-arg` options if you wish to skip certain uninteresting parts.  See valgrind man page for details.  Or perhaps combination of `--log-socket` and `valgrind-listener`?  It would be easier to filter output that way if you are up for little scripting.